# MongoDB : when does an error occur when querying in mongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I had a bug with my `findSomething` function.

```
function findSomething(req, res, next) {
  Myschema.findXXXById(req.params.xid, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) res.json({ status: 1, message: messages.NotFound });
    res.json({ status: 0, docsInfo: doc });
  });
}
```

The error I got was this

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>   at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)

I understand that the error is because my **if** condition is poorly defined so to understand where the error is coming from I want to find a possibility in which the query can encounter a error.

E.g.

```
if(err) {
     // how to get here   
}
```

I tried removing the data from the database so now when it does not get the data it still does not gives an error but return a null instead.

So I wanted to know how can one encounter an error in mongoDb

Comment: You could try using an invalid id (one that's not a valid `ObjectId`, say using `'abc'` instead of `req.params.xid`), but I'm not sure if those won't already get caught by Mongoose. But if you prefer, I can also explain to you why you got that error message ;D

Comment: what I guessed was, that an error occurs and the control goes to the next line which again is sending a response ,so Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. Thats why I just wanted to check how I can get that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You guessed right (in your comment): when an error occurs, you send back an error response but you don't stop the rest of the code from running.

You should make sure that you always call only one operation that will send headers and end the response; operations like that are `res.json()`, `res.send()`, `res.render()`, and some others.

You can restructure your code like this:

```
if (err) {
  res.json({ status: 1, message: messages.NotFound });
} else {
  res.json({ status: 0, docsInfo: doc });
}
```

Or even something like this:

```
if (err) {
  return res.json({ status: 1, message: messages.NotFound });
}
res.json({ status: 0, docsInfo: doc });
```

(the `return` statement there is not meant to return a value, but to stop the rest of the code from being run)

Comment: thanks robert this will do I guess. I just thought to reproduce this error but its not happening. anyway I will end it with this.

Comment: @sacDahal it's generally worthwhile to log errors that occur :)